# PHP. How generate page from php-html template in memory and save this into variable as string

Tags: php, templates

I have a list of files on a server, which are basic html templates with php inserts. I need to fill this template (with variables relates to the template) in memory and after that, for example, send via email and after that something else.

How to do this. I am new in php and know how to include template in the end of script work and it would outputs in the browser. But now I need some different tools.

It's possible I can't create correct question for google to get answer. Then I am asking for help.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, you are looking for `ob_start()` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

```
ob_start();
include('your_template.php');
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

But I would look around for some real template engine if I were you. Good luck!

Comment: thanks, It works.I was trying to look on these, but generally they are too complicated.

Comment: oh, this method sends headers before it will start.
Is it existing method to include variable's value to a script like a file with include(), or maybe it can be done with streams? But I don't understand how to send file to stream with variable to get result like with ob_start(). Hurmmm...